# How to handle with EditModeText in MarkupsCore Extension?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I want to implement all the markups core edit modes, and the `EditModeText` is giving me trouble. I did this to all of them, on clik -> changeEditMode, and only the text mode is not working:

```
mk_ext.changeEditMode(new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModeText(mk_ext));
```

I thought that I would be able to write something after entering in edit mode text, but I don't.

I've already read this post: [Playing with the new View & Data - Markup API](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/playing-with-the-new-view-data-markup-api.html) but no clue found. Do I have to create an input and pass the `input.value` to the `mk_ext.editMode` or something like that?

How to proceed?

EDIT:

I'm trying to do my own UI:

[image: own ui]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's working fine for me. Please make sure you don't have SVG reference conflicts or any other CSS-related issues.

This is how I added the extensions:

```
const config = {
          extensions: ['Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore', 'Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui']
        };
    
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('apsViewer'),config);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm trying to do my own UI, because this extension is very ugly, I've already tried to read the extension source code to deal with edit mode text but found no clue